# ¿ Equivalente de Java Encriptacion DES?

Tags: swift2, objective-c, encriptación

me gustaria saber como puedo.

Tengo un codigo en java

```
byte[] key24 = [-17, 55, 99, -54, -20, -99, -79, -34, -123, -100, -118, -42, -111, -108, -62, 123, -17, 55, 99, -54, -20, -99, -79, -34];

byte[] data = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 6, 0, 34, 96];
String algorithm = "DESede";
String mode = "DESede/ECB/NoPadding";


KeySpec confKey = new DESedeKeySpec(key24);
SecretKeyFactory spcKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
Cipher cifermode = Cipher.getInstance(mode);
SecretKey secretKey = spcKey.generateSecret(confKey); 
output = cifermode.doFinal(data);
System.err.println("cifrado: "+output);

resultado: [-101, 23, 28, -119, -62, -119, -18, 57]
```

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer eso mismo pero en objetive C o swift 2.3

gracias por su tiempo.

Hola es cifrado TripleDES.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si alguien le interesa, este es el equivalente en swift 2.3 usando la libreria: https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZSwiftCommonCrypto

Si no saben usarla, descargarn la version 0.8.3, abren el proyecto le dan a build, buscan el framework y listo solo arrastran y copian a su proyecto.

```
internal func enctpanch(){
    let key : [UInt8] = [239, 55, 99, 202, 236, 157, 177, 222, 133, 156, 138, 214, 145, 148, 194, 123, 239, 55, 99, 202, 236, 157, 177, 222];
    let data : [UInt8] = [255, 255, 255, 0, 6, 0, 34, 96];

    let ivBytes : [UInt8] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

    var cryptor = Cryptor(operation: .Encrypt, algorithm: .TripleDES, options: .ECBMode, key: key, iv: ivBytes );

    let cipherdata = cryptor.update(data)?.final();

    print("SerchCipher: \(cipherdata)");


}
```